# When quering over a base type why does the EF provider generate all those UNION All clauses

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

If I have a model that looks like this:
[image]

and I do a Linq to Entities query like this:

```
var c = MyContext.Contact.Count();
```

I'll get a SQL query that is as big as all out doors!

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM   [dbo].[Contacts] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        [UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM [dbo].[Companies] AS [Extent2]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent3]) AS [UnionAll1]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id]
        FROM [dbo].[Contractors] AS [Extent4]) AS [UnionAll2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [UnionAll2].[C1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        [UnionAll3].[Id] AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM [dbo].[Suppliers] AS [Extent5]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent6]) AS [UnionAll3]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        [Extent7].[Id] AS [Id]
        FROM [dbo].[People] AS [Extent7]) AS [UnionAll4] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [UnionAll4].[C1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

It seems to me that this should be a very simple query that executes over the base type table (Contact in this case)  The model that I've included here is a watered down sample of what I'm working with.  As you can imagine with a hierarchy 6 levels deep rather than 3 the SQL queries on anything other than the  most derived types are very expensive.

Is there any way to tweek the query, or the model definition to reduce the unnecessary complexity of this query.

Comment: Not sure of the specifics for this code but you may want to have a look at this article.  http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/04/21/38598/

Comment: @John, Thanks for the link.  In my case the Count() is what I want not Any, although the point is well taken.  I would add howerver, than Any or Count, the resulting SQL is just as horiffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [arguably a bug, and will be fixed RSN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework).

Comment: Not the news i was hoping to hear, but thanks for the confirmation.