# How would you use EF in a typical Business Layer/Data Access Layer/Stored Procedures set up?

Tags: entity-framework

Whenever I watch a demo regarding the Entity Framework the demonstrator simply sets up some tables and performs Inserts, Updates and Deletes using automatically created code stubs but never shows any use of stored procedures. It seems to me that this is executing SQL from the client.

In my experience this is not particular good practice so I am presuming that my understanding of the Entity Framework is wrong.

Similarly WCF RIA Services demos use the EF and the demos are always the same. Can anyone shed any light on how you would use EF in a typical Business Layer/Data Access Layer/Stored Procedures set up.

I think I am confused and shouldn't be!!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with executing SQL from the client. Most (if not all) of the problems that it might cause are in fact not there when using something like EF. For instance:

1. Client generated SQL might cause runtime syntax errors. This is not unlikely since the description of your query is mostly checked on compile time (assuming that the generator itself doesn't generate invalid SQL, which is also unlikely)
2. Client generated SQL might be inefficient. This is not true with modern database software which have query caches. EF works in a way that's compatible with query caches, i.e. it generates the same SQL consistently (as long as you use the same code consistently) and uses parameters for varying data.
3. Client generated SQL might be insecure (SQL injections and whatnot). This is all handled by the generator, which uses parameters for your values and does not interpolate user input into the query itself.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. My instincts were telling me EF couldn't have developed without consideration for the things you mention. I was especially concerned about security. Now I feel freed to embrace it more and put in the time and effort to really 'get it'.

Comment: If you have extremely 'thin-clients' do you think there would be performance problems running queries at client-side.

Comment: @EzaBlade: The process of building a query is not that complicated, all it does is it takes an expression tree and transforms that into a string of SQL and a collection of parameters. I don't think any client capable of running the .NET framework in the first place should have any trouble doing that. The database server is the thing doing the expensive work in any case.

Answer (score 4):

Back in the old Client / Server days, it used to be considered good practice to do all db updates using stored procedures.

But now, it's perfectly acceptable to have an O/RM generate SQL and run directly against DB.

Answer (score 1):

> never shows any use of stored procedures

Take a look at this video: [**Using Your Own Stored Procedures to Insert, Update and Delete Entities in Entity Framework**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff657848.aspx).

Note that there are a lot of other videos on that topic there that are certainly worth watching!

Comment: @Xlll I guess it's because the user asked why the demos should no stored procedures. Your example should you how to use them.

Comment: `but never shows any use of stored procedures`: the video I posted about shows how to use stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Well, part of the reason why executing sql in stored procedures is a good idea is that it gives you a level of abstraction - when db changes inevitably occur, you make a change in a single place (the proc) rather than a dozen places (all the places where you were calling the client sql). Entity Framework provides this layer of abstraction through the data model, and you have the same advantage.

There are some other reasons why you might want to look at procs, like security granularity (only allowing certain users the right to execute), and some minor performance differences. Ultimately, you have to decide for yourself what the right trade-off is. EF is an attempt to dramatically reduce the developer time spent creating a data layer, with the trade-offs listed above.

Comment: I would counter, that when a schema changes you make changes in dozens, and dozens of stored procs, not "a single place". IN fact verifying that you've not missed an SP is next to impossible out of the box. The big win with that EF (and the like) offers is that a schema changes propogates through the EF model into the generated classes, which in turn triggers compile errors --- something that stored procs don't offer.

Answer (score 1):

The legend is that [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) once said "It's not a real demo unless someone drags a datagrid"  (pg 478 Silverlight 4 In Action, Pete Brown)

You have to remember that demos, are all about selling software, and not at all about communicating best practice.  So your observations about the demos are absolutely correct, they cover the basics, and leave it to the observer to fill in the blanks.

As to your comment about Stored Procedures, and various answers to your question about the generator.  The generator is good, and getting better. Howerver there are certain circumstances when it will generate completely unusable queries. (see my SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126668/when-quering-over-a-base-type-why-does-the-ef-provider-generate-all-those-union-a) and [discussed on the ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/08/17/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx))

Therefore there are occasions when hand crafted queries are your only recourse (either by way of stored proc, table value functions, views etc)