# Does Entity Framework Use Reflection and Hurt Performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I ultimately have two areas with a few questions each about Entity Framework, but let me give a little background so you know what context I am asking for this information in.

At my place of work my team is planning a complete re-write of our application structure so we can adhere to more modern standards. This re-write includes a completely new data layer project. In this project most of the team wants to use Entity Framework. I too would like to use it because I am very familiar with it from my using it in personal projects. However, one team member is opposed to this vehemently, stating that Entity Framework uses reflection and kills performance. His other argument is that EF uses generated SQL that is far less efficient than stored procedures. I'm not so familiar with the inner-workings of EF and my searches haven't turned up anything extremely useful.

Here are my questions. I've tried to make them as specific as possible. If you need some clarification please ask.

**Issue 1 Questions - Reflection**

1. Is this true about EF using reflection and hurting performance?
2. Where does EF use reflection if it does?
3. Are there any resources that compare performance? Something that I could use to objectively compare technologies for data access in .NET and then present it to my team?

**Issue 2 Questions - SQL**

1. What are the implications of this?
2. Is it possible to use stored procedures to populate EF entities?
3. Again are there some resources that compare the generated queries with stored procedures, and what the implications of using stored procedures to populate entities (if you can) would be?

I did some searching on my own but didn't come up with too much about EF under the hood.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it does like many other ORMs (NHibernate) and useful frameworks (DI tools). For example **WPF** cannot work without Reflection.

While the performance implications of using Reflection has not changed much over the course of the last 10 years since .NET 1.0 (although there has been improvements), with the faster hardware and general trend towards readability, it is becoming less of a concern now.

Remember that main performance hit is at the time of **reflecting aka binding** which is reading the type metadata into xxxInfo (such as `MethodInfo`) and this happens at the application startup.

**Calling** reflected method is definitely slower but is not considered much of an issue.

---

### UPDATE

I have used Reflector to look at the source code of EF and **I can confirm it heavily uses Reflection.**

Comment: Now see this is contradictory to a previous answer. Do you maybe have some resources I could point to for this?

Comment: OK I will update my answer. Let me find the code where it does.

Comment: Please see my update. Yes, it does **heavy reflection**, as I imagined.

Answer (score 5):

Answer for Issue 1:

You can take a look at exactly what is output by EF by examining the `Foo.Designer.cs` file that is generated.  You will see that the resulting container does not use reflection, but does make heavy use of generics.

Here are the places that Entity Framework certainly does use reflection:

1. The `Expression<T>` interface is used in creating the SQL statements.  The extension methods in `System.Linq` are based around the idea of Expression Trees which use the types in `System.Reflection` to represent function calls and types, etc.
2. When you use a stored procedure like this:  `db.ExecuteStoreQuery<TEntity>("GetWorkOrderList @p0, @p1", ...)`, Entity Framework has to populate the entity, and at very least has to check that the `TEntity` type provided is tracked.

---

Answer for Issue 2:

It is true that the queries are often strange-looking but that does not indicate that it is less efficient.  You would be hard pressed to come up with a query whose *acutal query plan* is worse.

On top of that, you certainly **can use Stored Procedures**, or even Inline SQL with entity framework, for querying and for Creating, Updating and Deleting.

---

Aside:

Even if it used reflection everywhere, and didn't let you use stored procedures, why would that be a reason not to use it?  I think that you need to have your coworker **prove it**.

Comment: Do you maybe know of some good resources I can point to for this information? I did examine the generated CS files but I'm not completely familiar with them, I just thought maybe it was using it somewhere else. I need some hard facts to draw upon so I can make a presentation that he can't argue about.

Comment: @Chevex: I am not a lawyer, but I would think that you would be safe examining the source code in System.Data.Entity with .NET Reflector.

Comment: Hmmm, I will research that a bit more. I just wish that some of this research was already done for me somewhere on the web :P

Comment: Regarding your Aside: Unfortunately I'm the one having to prove that this will benefit us and not hurt us. For some reason management respects his egotistical opinions far more than they deserve to be respected.

Answer (score 4):

I can comment on Issue 2 about Generated EF Queries are less efficient than Stored Procedures.

Basically yes sometimes the generated queries are a mess and need some tuning.  There are many tools to help you correct this, SQL Profiler, LinqPad, and others.  But in the end the Generated Queries may look like crap but they do typically run quickly.

Yes you can map EF entities to Procedures.  This is possible and will allow you to control some of the nasty generated EF queries.  In turn you could also map views to your entities allowing you to control how the views select the data.

I cannot think of resources but I must say this.  The comparison to using EF vs SQL stored procedures is apples to oranges.  EF provides a robust way of mapping your Database to your code directly. This combined with LINQ to Entity queries will allow your developers to quickly produce code.   EF is an ORM where as SQL store procedures is not.

Comment: +1, good answer. I'm not really comparing EF to stored procs so much as EF's generated SQL to stored procs. So I feel that is a valid comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The entity framework likely uses reflection, but I would not expect this to hurt performance.  High-end librairies that are based on reflection typically use light-weight code generation to mitigate the cost.  They inspect each type just once to generate the code and then use the generated code from that point on.  You pay a little when your application starts up, but the cost is negligible from there on out.

As for stored procedures, they are faster than plain old queries, but this benefit is often oversold.  The primary advantage is that the database will precompile and store the execution plan for each stored procedure.  But the database will also cache the execution plans it creates for plain old SQL queries.  So this benefit varies a great deal depending on the number and type of queries your application executes.  And yes, you can use stored procedures with the entity framework if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if EF uses reflection (I don't believe it does... I can't think of what information would have to be determined at run-time); but even if it did, so what?

Reflection is used all over the place in .NET (e.g. serializers), some of which are called all of the time.

Reflection really isn't all that slow; especially in the context of this discussion.  I imagine the overhead of making a database call, running the query, returning it and hydrating the objects dwarf the performance overhead of reflection.

---

**EDIT**

Article by Rick Strahl on reflection performance: [.Net Reflection and Performance](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/351.aspx)(old, but still relevant).

Comment: This guy is dead convinced that reflection is horrible. Do you maybe have some links to resources I can use in a presentation to the team? I need some hard facts to throw out so he can't just rattle off anecdotal claims.

Comment: If we were using WPF or he actually liked WPF that would work :P

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework generated sql queries are fine, even if they are not exactly as your DBA would write by hand.

**However** it generates complete rubbish when it comes to queries over base types.  If you are planning on using a Table-per-Type inheritance scheme, **and** you anticipate queries on the base types, then I would recommend proceeding with caution.

For a more detailed explanation of this bizarre shortcoming see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126668/when-quering-over-a-base-type-why-does-the-ef-provider-generate-all-those-union-a).  take special note of the accepted answer to that question --- this is arguably a bug.

As for the issue of reflection -- I think your co-worker is grasping at straws.  It's highly unlikely that reflection will be the root cause of any performance problems in your app.

Comment: I completely agree with you about reflection. I will check out your question you linked. +1

Answer (score 0):

EF uses reflection. I didn't check it by I think it is the main point of the mapping when materializing instance of entity from database record. You will say what is a column's name and what is the name of a property and when a data reader is executed you must somehow fill the property which you only know by its name.

I believe that all these "performance like" issues are solved correctly by caching needed information for mapping. Performance impact caused by reflection will probably be nothing comparing to network communication with the server, executing the complex query, etc.

If we talk about EF performance check these two documents: [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/02/04/exploring-the-performance-of-the-ado-net-entity-framework-part-1.aspx) and [Part2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/02/11/exploring-the-performance-of-the-ado-net-entity-framework-part-2.aspx). It describes some reason why people sometimes think the EF is very slow.

Are stored procedures faster then EF queries? My answer: I don't think so. The main advantage of the linq is that you can build your query in the application. This is extreamly handy when you need anything like list filtering, paging and sorting + changing number of displayed columns, loading realted entities etc. If you want to implement this in a stored procedure you will either have tens of procedures for diffent query configurations or you will use a dynamic sql. Dynamic sql is exactly what uses EF. But in case of EF that query has compile time validation which is not the case of plain SQL. The only difference in performance is the amount of transfered data when you send whole query to the server and when you send only exec procecdeure and parameters.

It is true that queries are sometimes very strange. Especially inheritance produces sometimes bad queries. But this is already solved. You can always use custom stored procedure or SQL query to return entities, complex types or custom types. EF will materialize results for you so you don't need to bother with data readers etc.

If you want to be objective when presenting Entity framework you should also mention its cons. Entity framework doesn't support command batching. If you need to update or insert multiple entities each sql command have its own roundrip to database. Because of that you should not use EF for data migrations etc. Another problem with EF is almost no hooks for extensibility.