# Why does Entity Framework add unnecessary (AND [param] IS NOT NULL) in WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Given this simple model:

```
public partial class UserColumnGrid
    {
        public int UserColumnGridID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int ColumnGridID { get; set; }
        public int ColumnWidth { get; set; }
        public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

        public virtual ColumnGrid ColumnGrid { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

And this simple query: *(userID is an int)*

```
dbContext.UserColumnGrid.Where(ucg => ucg.UserID == userID).ToList();
```

The following query is generated:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[UserColumnGridID]  AS [UserColumnGridID],
       [Extent1].[UserID]            AS [UserID],
       [Extent1].[ColumnGridID]      AS [ColumnGridID],
       [Extent1].[ColumnWidth]       AS [ColumnWidth],
       [Extent1].[IsVisible]         AS [IsVisible]
FROM   [dbo].[UserColumnGrid] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  ([Extent1].[UserID] = 1 /* @p__linq__0 */)
       AND (1 /* @p__linq__0 */ IS NOT NULL)
```

**Why is this AND NOT NULL criterion added? The database doesn't allow for nulls in that field, and an int can't be null in .net**

This happens all over my queries. It's pretty annoying, but is it impacting performance?

How can I get rid of it?

This is on a database-first model.

Comment: How is the captured variable `userID` defined?

Comment: It's an int passed to the function containing this query: public void LoadUserSettings(int userID)

Comment: I presume that userid is defined with NOT NULL or as PK is this so?

Comment: Yes, as I mentionned it is NOT NULL.

Comment: Even if it wasn't, I don't see why this would make sense given that I'm passing it an int (which can't be null).

Comment: This is strange, but performance-wise I cannot see it make a big difference. In fact it might give the optimizer more information to work with (or work around an optimizer limitation). It might be useless in this particular query, but this pattern might help others. In any case a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got rid of the extra "(AND [param] IS NOT NULL) in WHERE clause" by marking the property in the model class required using data annotation.

I am using EF 6.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it would make the check. Think about how Entity Framework has to construct the query from your LINQ statement. It uses a lot of reflection (as shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396290/does-entity-framework-use-reflection-and-hurt-performance)) to get the job done. As such, using reflection means that it's probably not spending the time thinking about what type a specific field is, or if it's nullable or not--especially since it could just add that null check and be done with the query.

My guess is that that was done on purpose since using reflection to grab the type and then to see if it is or isn't nullable could possibly be a major performance hit--especially for any really complicated query (like one with a lot of parameters). It might not be necessary, but I think it makes things a lot simpler for everyday use.

Comment: How about (any) impact on the SQL server? It just strikes me as weird since I've been mainly using NHibernate these past two years and it doesn't have that behavior.

Comment: Any impact on SQL would be negligible. Once the query is constructed and carried over to SQL it would be run rather quickly. Adding one simple clause shouldn't have that much of an impact. As far as NHibernate goes, I don't know your personal experience with it, but I used it at my first job followed by EF at my second job, and I personally feel that EF does the job a lot faster than NHibernate.

Comment: Thanks. I actually first started with EF on the big project I'm working on, but had too many problems with it (it was pretty new) and I decided to switch to NHibernate. Two years later I'm considering switching back to EF because it seems pretty mature and nice now.

Comment: Oh yeah. That's what happens when you have a large company like Microsoft pouring money into something: It gets better rather quickly. And then, after they made it better, they now have it open-source. Epic win for Microsoft.