# ADO.Net EF, Inheritance Table shows, but not the model

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, inheritance, ado.net

I have created a Entity named MediaItem which is Abstract and Game inherits form it. I create the database automatically and I get a table MediaItems and MediaItems_Game.

The issue is when I do the following in my ASP.Net Controller:

private Models.DBContainer dataModel = new DBContainer();

dataModel. ---> Intellisense shows me MediaItem but I can find no way to either navigate to or use MediaItems_Game, how can I solve this? i.e. How can I grab a list of 'Games' with some 'WHERE' constraints on another table (not pictured).

Any info is appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how inheritance in EF works. You have only single set of parent type. If you want to get just games you will use `OfType` method:

```
var games = dataModel.MediaItems.OfType<Game>().ToList();
```

Comment: When do you query the base table (Game) take a close look at the SQL that is generated.  You'll see that it ends up querying the derived table anyway.  There hasn't been enough said able the performance disaster TPT inheritance results in (at least when querying base classes)  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126668/when-quering-over-a-base-type-why-does-the-ef-provider-generate-all-those-union-a

Comment: Aha! Thank you :) I'm starting to understand this now. I appreciate the help you have provided me with during the course of today.

Comment: Also, How would I Eager load from other tables? Do I use a .Include? How would this be formed, or should I ask this tomorrow as another question? Thanks.

Comment: You must use combination of `OfType` to get derived entity and then `Include`.